# Clipping around a parallelogram

Tags: tikz-pgf

To illustrate the concept of linear combinations in 2-space, I'm creating a handout with a non-rectangular coordinate system based on two linearly independent vectors. I've used a series of parallel lines to achieve this. I would like to clip the figure so as to show only the region where the lines actually intersect. That boundary of that region is a parallelogram. How might I do this? I could manually adjust the domain for each line, but that would be very tedious. Moreover, if you have a more elegant way to achieve my overall goal, please do share.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)-5});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)-4});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)-3});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)-2});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)-1});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+1});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+2});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+3});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+4});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+5});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)-5});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)-4});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)-3});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)-2});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)-1});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+1});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+2});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+3});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+4});
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+5});
        \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,.666) node[above left] {$\mathbf{u}$};
        \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,-.333) node[below ] {$\mathbf{v}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TikZ also supports different coordinate systems. The vectors for directions *x* and *y* (and *z*) can be set explicitly via vectors of the `xy canvas` coordinate system:

```
x={(1cm, 1cm)},
y={(1cm, -.5cm)},
```

Then the grid lines and the vector lines can be specified by simple integer numbers of the uv (=xy) coordinate system. Clipping is not needed at all.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      >=latex,
      % font=\footnotesize,
      x={(1cm, 1cm)},
      y={(1cm, -.5cm)},
    ]
      \def\xmin{-2}
      \def\xmax{3}
      \def\ymin{-2}
      \def\ymax{3}
      \draw[thin, dashed]
        \foreach \x in {\xmin, ..., \xmax} {
          (\x, \ymin) -- (\x, \ymax)
        }
        \foreach \y in {\ymin, ..., \ymax} {
          (\xmin, \y) -- (\xmax, \y)
        }
      ;
      \draw[<->, very thick]
        (1, 0) node[above left] {$\mathbf{u}$}
        -- (0, 0)
        -- (0, 1) node[below] {$\mathbf{v}$}
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is a very nice solution! I never knew that tikz could so easily define other coordinate systems!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
        \clip
          (0,-5) -- (5,0) -- (5,2.5) -- (0,5) -- (-5,0) -- (-5,-2.5) -- cycle;
        \foreach \Value in {-5,...,5}
          {
            \draw[-,thin,dashed,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+\Value});
            \draw[-,thin,dashed,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+\Value});
          }  
        \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,.666) node[above left] {$\mathbf{u}$};
        \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,-.333) node[below ] {$\mathbf{v}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that using a `\foreach` considerably simplifies the code. Also, simce you are drawing straight lines it doesn't add much to say `samples=100` (except that it makes the compilation time longer).

If you want to get a true parallelogram, the modification is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
        \clip
          (0,-3) -- (4.66666,1.66666) -- (0,4) -- (-4.66666,-0.66666) -- cycle;
        \foreach \Value in {-3,...,4}
          {
            \draw[-,thin,dashed,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(\x)+\Value});
            \draw[-,thin,dashed,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{(-1/2)*(\x)+\Value});
          }  
        \draw[->,very thick] (-0.66666,0.33333) -- ++(0.666,.666) node[above left] {$\mathbf{u}$};
        \draw[->,very thick] (-0.66666,0.33333) -- ++(.666,-.333) node[below ] {$\mathbf{v}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image: clip to parallelogram]

You can use `\clip <path specification>;` to specify the area to clip everything within its scope to. Here, everything else in the picture is within the scope of the clipping, as this is just used as the first move within the `tikzpicture` environment.

If I've understood correctly, you want something like:

```
    \clip  (0,-5) -- +(-5,2.5) -- (-5,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,2.5)  -- (5,0) -- cycle;
```

This is not a parallelogram because two corners are not drawn in your original plots. Obviously, you could adjust this as required.

You can also specify the plots much more concisely using loops. Here, an inner loop over `\i` iterates through values from `-5` to `5` and an outer loop over `\j` iterates through the two values `1` and `.5`. This reduces the code for the existing plots to

```
    \foreach \j in {1,-.5}
      \foreach \i in {-5,...,5}
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{\j*(\x)+\i});;
```

With the clipping and the two commands you use to create the arrows, this completes the image.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,>=latex,font=\footnotesize]
    \clip  (0,-5) -- +(-5,2.5) -- (-5,0) -- (0,5) -- (5,2.5)  -- (5,0) -- cycle;
    \foreach \j in {1,-.5}
      \foreach \i in {-5,...,5}
        \draw[-,thin,dashed,samples=100,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{\j*(\x)+\i});;
    \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,.666) node[above left] {$\mathbf{u}$};
    \draw[->,very thick] (0,0) -- (.666,-.333) node[below] {$\mathbf{v}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve. I marked this solution as being useful, but due to the simplicity of Heiko Oberdiek's solution, I accepted that one. Thanks!